# Get IP Address Information such as Country, LatLong, City using Google Maps Data API

Tags: c#, json, google-maps, geolocation

Can I use Google Maps Data API to get the IP Address informations such as Country, LatLong, City, etc. The result will be in JSON or XML format that I can parse through C#. Is there any C# Library for Google Maps Data API?

I found this interesting site
http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php

this guys even offer their IP address location database
http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php

Answer (score 0):

Description: http://s.site90.com/api-xml.php

phpcode:

```
<?
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];// or ex. "92.32.207.124"
$data = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("http://s.site90.com/api/xml.php?type=ip&ip=".$ip));
//echo print_r($data);
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.utf8_decode($data->ip->countryimage->attributes()->small).'"> '.utf8_decode($data->ip->location->attributes()->city).' ('.utf8_decode($data->ip->location->attributes()->region).')';
?>
```